# socket.io - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm building a forum where two users after connections can post a status then comment on them.
For comments, i used socket.io .

In console i'm getting this error each few seconds :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O05nump net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How to fix this error ?

---

I installed **express**, **nodemon** and **socket.io** in my *socket server*:

- **Socket server:**

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "socket",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.17.3",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
  "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
const io = require("socket.io")(4000, {
cors: {
    origin: "http//localhost:3000",
},
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A new user is connected !');
})
io.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('User has left !');
});
```

---

- **Front:**

Also, i installed **socket.io-client** in client (front), then in my web page, i added this code :

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
export default () => {

  //implement socket
  const socket = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
      socket.current = io("ws://localhost/4000")
  }, [])

return (
  //some html code
)
}
```

---

- **My project tree:**

Project Forum

```
├── back     
├── client
   └──index.jsx
└── socket
   └──package.json
   └──app.js
```

---

- **Console Visual Studio Code:**
  Visual studio code's console shows this only how many times i refresh browser or ctrl+S the code:

  ```
  [nodemon] starting 'node apde app.js'
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a slash instead of semi-colon:
`socket.current = io("ws://localhost:4000")`

Comment: typo error fixed, **BUT i am still getting the same issue**. Console log still doesn't show me ( A new user is connected ) whenever i login to forum...

Comment: You also need to use `emit` acording to their documentation: https://socket.io/docs/v4/

Answer (score 0):

```
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 2018;

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"]
  }
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("ok");
    console.log(socket.id);
    // io.in(roomID).emit()
    socket.emit("WELCOME_MESSAGE", ` ${socket.id} welcome!! `);
  });
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.